# How do I alternate numeric values of 3 (numeric) columns and put that into one column?

Tags: r

This is my first time asking a question here, so forgive me if it is not entirely clear. I am working in R btw!

I have a df that consists of 3 numeric columns with 26 rows each. Lets say `X`, `Y`, `Z`. I want to put these values into 1 column (called 'groupdata').
My desired result would look like:

```
X1, Y1, Z1, X2, Y2, Z2, ... etc.
```

Right now, I tried:

```
groupdata <- rep(c(X, Y, Z))
```

However, this only lists the values like: `X1:X26`, `Y1:Y26`, `Z1:Z26`

Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: Do you need `unlist(df)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have a data frame `df`:

```
X <- rnorm(26)
Y <- runif(26)
Z <- rnorm(26, 5)

df <- data.frame(X, Y, Z)

#              X           Y        Z
# 1  -1.83922080 0.774802928 5.241226
# 2  -0.27454727 0.061767963 7.852047
# 3  -1.04591385 0.531488041 4.922031
# 4   0.05362313 0.069112943 3.992769
# 5  -1.64507884 0.495397887 4.338495
# 6   0.82140902 0.850252364 6.257287
# ...
```

You can turn it into a matrix, rotate it and manually change the matrix's dimensions to a single value (hence casting it to a vector) as such:

```
mat <- t(as.matrix(df))
dim(mat) <- prod(dim(mat)) # in this case 26*3 = 78

# [1] -1.839220796  0.774802928  5.241226068 -0.274547267  0.061767963
# [6]  7.852047069 -1.045913855  0.531488041  4.922030849  0.053623133
# [11]  0.069112943  3.992769370 ...
```

#### Edit:

As commented by Darren Tsai, there is a way more elegant solution:

```
c(t(df))

# [1] -1.839220796  0.774802928  5.241226068 -0.274547267  0.061767963
# [6]  7.852047069 -1.045913855  0.531488041  4.922030849  0.053623133
# [11]  0.069112943  3.992769370 ...
```

Comment: `as.matrix()` is not necessary. In addition, your method can be simplified as `c(t(df))`, which doesn't need to adjust the dimension of data manually.

Comment: Thanks @DarrenTsai, edited my post to include your simplification